# android - Change image position in imageview using glide

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-glide

I'm working with Glide in wallpaper app
I load the image with glide and show in imageview, but the image after loaded is on top of the imageview.

How can i fix this and bring it in the center of imageview?

Code:

```
Glide.with(this)
      .load(data)
      .fitCenter()
      .into(wallpaper);
```

XML:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/img_aksneveshte"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

[image]

Comment: Please put your xml code

Comment: Are you sure your `ImageView` spans the full height of the screen? Also, double check you didn't enable something like `adjustViewBounds` on it. As suggested, we can be of more help if you add the contents of the relevant layout file.

Comment: I update the post . adjustViewBounds doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even you have Answer I can provide more information

[Glid](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) can use scale type assigned in your image view

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

so add it to your ImageView

to be like this

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/img_aksneveshte"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />
```

here is Glid read scale type and [use it](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/v3.5.2/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/GenericRequestBuilder.java#L638)

```
    if (!isTransformationSet && view.getScaleType() != null) {
                switch (view.getScaleType()) {
                    case CENTER_CROP:
// in case you set image scale center crop
                        applyCenterCrop();
                        break;
                    case FIT_CENTER:
                    case FIT_START:
                    case FIT_END:
                        applyFitCenter();
                        break;
                    //$CASES-OMITTED$
                    default:
                        // Do nothing.
                }
            }
```